# How to correctly create and import packages in Java

Tags: java

*I am using Netbeans 8.1 and Java 8.*

I have a Java program named "MyFrame.java" and I want to create a package with its classes and methods - I call this package "myframe" and it is located at "\Lab\MyFrame\src\myframe". See picture: [image]

(*Ignore the red lines - this is a dummy version*).

The class file is created after compiling, using the command "javac MyFrame.java", in the same directory \myframe. Now I want to import the package "myframe" in a new Java file "MoreButtons.java". So it would look like this and for convenience I save it in \src:
[image]

Compiling and executing MoreButtons.java works fine. The package has been imported. But now MyFrame.java is a bit trickier to execute: the naïve approach yields: [image]

Translation: **Error: Could not find or load main class**
This seems to be quite a common problem and one of the solutions is simply to add the directory (\myframe) to the PATH environment variable. However, doing this still produced the error.

> 1) What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
>
> 2) What is the *correct* way to create and import custom-made packages in Java?

Comment: Part answer to your first question.
What you are doing wrong I ain't sure unless I see complete code. But to fix it you could try one thing. Since you are using netbeans, right click on libraries under your project and click on Add Project, and add the project which contains myFrame.java to your moreButtons project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that terminal is at path `Lab\MyFrame\src`:

```
javac myframe\MyFrame.java MoreButtons.java
java -cp .; myframe.MyFrame
```

**P.S.** (`/`,`:`=linux/mac) or (`\`,`;`=windows)
[image: output 1]
[image: output 2]

MyFrame.java

```
package myframe;

public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    public MyFrame(String title){
        super(title);
        setSize(200,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MoreButtons.java

```
public class MoreButtons {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        new myframe.MyFrame("More Buttons");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm weird. Compiling works fine in both cmd and bash, but I can only run MyFrame from cmd (using `java -cp .; myframe.MyFrame`) but in bash the command `java -cp .: myframe.MyFrame` still yields above error.

Comment: though you using bash, you are still on windows platform

Comment: Using windows syntax in bash does not work either :/

Comment: *I can only run MyFrame from cmd*, what was that?